# Sending message to facebook account from server in java

Tags: facebook, messenger

Recently I began to using facebook sdk and I would like to ask how I could sending messages to facebook messenger from my server to the people who are using my android app .

Comment: It is not possible

Comment: Is there any other possible way ?

Comment: It is not possible means it is not possible. If there was a way to do it then it wouldn't be impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use de Messenger API Graph 2.6.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform

You will need a web server to host your webhook page and receive and sent the messages for who follow your Facebook Bot.